# Laravel: Setting a Default Value for Blank/Null Input

Tags: laravel, schema, field, default

This is the code in the migration:

```
$table->string('role')->default('Standard');
```

When I leave the input box blank, it gives me an error:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'role' cannot be null

How do we set the default value to "Standard" if the input box is left blank?

Code for Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //return ['message' => 'I have your data'];
        $request->validate([
            'firstname' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'lastname' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
        return User::create([
        'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'phone' => $request['phone'],
        'role' => $request['role'],
        'usernotes' => $request['usernotes'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']), //make sure to import Hash: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
        'created_by' => $request['created_by'],
        'updated_by' => $request['updated_by'],
    ]);
    }
```

Comment: `'role' => request()->get('role') ?? 'Standard'` should ffix it, but I will not be able to help you without some more details.

Comment: @Akshay Khale here is more of the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `$request['role']` should be null which is causing the problem since the `role` field is not Nullable.

What you can do is, add the dwfault value if the role is null, just made following changes in your code and it should work.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //return ['message' => 'I have your data'];
    $request->validate([
        'firstname' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'lastname' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
    ]);
    return User::create([
    'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
    'email' => $request['email'],
    'phone' => $request['phone'],
    'role' => $request['role'] ?? 'Standard',
    'usernotes' => $request['usernotes'],
    'password' => Hash::make($request['password']), //make sure to import Hash: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    'created_by' => $request['created_by'],
    'updated_by' => $request['updated_by'],
]);
}
```

That should fix the issue.

Explanation: I am using Null coalescing (??) operator of PHP which will replace the null value with `'Standard'`. It works only is PHP 7+, if you have a lower version of PHP then you can consider using the Ternary operator(?:).

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: So, what is the point of writing the default value in the migration file? If you going to write it by yourself when you create?

Answer (score 1):

use nullable();

```
$table->string('role')->default('Standard')->nullable();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for responding. I tried nullable but it leaves the field empty when it is saved.